# Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9 when camera permissions changed

Tags: ios, debugging

I am getting this error when I change camera permissions off when the app is in use

Comment: Please mention the full details, along with error and code

Comment: in my app I need to use camera preview ...when I get camera permissions alert to allow/deny, I allowed and turned off camera permission in settings ...then in Xcode am getting `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`.. I tried with exceptional breakpoints too to catch the error..but no use

Comment: A good practice is to check for the camera permission every time you are going to access it. Can you put break points on where you access the cameras?